# Pattern matching to find what numeric type is in Spark Row

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to write function to multiply all numbers in Spark Rdd. There is only one column with numbers.
The problem is: I don't know what type of Numeric values it will be. So I'm trying to make it like this:

```
        def mult(a: Row, b: Row): Row = {
          (a(0), b(0)) match {
            case (v: java.lang.Double, v1: java.lang.Double) => Row(v.asInstanceOf[Double] * v1.asInstanceOf[Double])
            case (v: java.lang.Long, v1: java.lang.Long) => Row((v.asInstanceOf[Long] * v1.asInstanceOf[Long]).toDouble)
            case (v: java.lang.Float, v1: java.lang.Float) => Row((v.asInstanceOf[Float] * v1.asInstanceOf[Float]).toDouble)
            case (v: java.lang.Integer, v1: java.lang.Integer) => Row((v.asInstanceOf[Int] * v1.asInstanceOf[Int]).toDouble)
            case _ => throw new Exception ("Incorrect data type in column")
          }
        }

    val result = df.rdd.reduce((a, b) => mult(a, b))
```

And like this:

```
    def mult(a: Row, b: Row): Row = {
      (a(0), b(0)) match {
        case (v: DoubleType, v1: DoubleType) => Row(v.asInstanceOf[Double] * v1.asInstanceOf[Double])
        case (v: LongType, v1: LongType) => Row((v.asInstanceOf[Long] * v1.asInstanceOf[Long]).toDouble)
        case (v: FloatType, v1: FloatType) => Row((v.asInstanceOf[Float] * v1.asInstanceOf[Float]).toDouble)
        case (v: IntegerType, v1: IntegerType) => Row((v.asInstanceOf[Int] * v1.asInstanceOf[Int]).toDouble)
        case _ => throw new Exception ("Incorrect data type in column")
      }
    }
```

But at run time I'm getting

> java.lang.Exception: Incorrect data type in column

When I'm doing

```
println(v.getClass)
```

I'm always getting

> class java.lang.Double

I test it with this data:

```
val data = List(
        List(444.1235D),
        List(67.5335D),
        List(69.5335D),
        List(677.5335D),
        List(47.5335D)
      )

      val rdd = sparkContext.parallelize(data).map(Row.fromSeq(_))
      val schema = StructType(Array(
        StructField("value", DataTypes.DoubleType, false)
      ))

      val df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
      df.createOrReplaceTempView(tableName)
```

Then the same for Long:

```
  val data1 = List(
        List(555L),
        List(955L),
        List(575L),
        List(355L),
        List(615L),
        List(0L)
      )

      val rdd1 = sparkContext.parallelize(data1).map(Row.fromSeq(_))
      val schema1 = StructType(Array(
        StructField("value", DataTypes.LongType, false)
      ))

      val df1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd1, schema1)
      df1.createOrReplaceTempView(tableName1)
```

What I'm doing wrong and how this can be achieved?

Comment: Your code works for me with no exception (using Spark 2.0.2) for a trivial input example (`Seq(2, 4).toDF("col1")`) - please provide sample data for which it doesn't.

Comment: @TzachZohar I've added sample data I use

Comment: works for me with your sample data too... maybe you're using a different Spark version?

Comment: Works fine for me (Spark 1.6.3)

Comment: Strange thing. What version is working fine for you? With DoubleType or with java.lang.Double?

Comment: Didn't found what was wrong. Just changed my code to: `val multipl: Double = df.rdd.map(_(0).toString.toDouble).reduce(_ * _)` without using own function